# kubernetes Unknown field "name" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvFromSource

Tags: kubernetes

Here my command line:

```
kubectl apply -f postgres.secret.yaml \
-f postgres.configmap.yaml \
-f postgres.volume.yaml \
-f postgres.deployment.yaml \
-f postgres.service.yaml
```

and i got and error as this picture :
[image]

Here my yaml file deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:12
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
              name: postgres-secret
            - configMapRef:
              name: postgres-configmap
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgres-pv
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

And i got an error : Unknown field "name" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvFromSource
I have checked this error everyobdy says that is from space from envFrom however it is rightly indent as the solution they propose.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The indentation is wrong.

It should be:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:12
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: postgres-secret
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-configmap
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgres-pv
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

i.e. `name` should be indented under the `secretRef` or `configMapRef` fields